# Continuity of argmax on space of functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, optimization

Is the map $T:\mathcal{F}\to K:f\mapsto \operatorname{argmax}_{x\in K} f(x)$ continuous? Here $\mathcal{F}$ is some space of functions under the topology of pointwise convergence (although other topologies are OK too if this is too weak), and $(K,d)$ is a metric space.

Edit: Assume $\mathcal{F}$ and $K$ are such that $Tf\in K$ is always unique. Or, consider $T$ to be a set-valued map under the Hausdorff topology.

Comment: This is not even a map.

Comment: Keyword to look for: "continuous selector". Warning: Even finding a measurable selector can be tricky.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429961/8157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=[-1,1]$ and let $\mathcal F$ be all the functions of form $f_a:x\mapsto ax$ for $a\in\mathbb R$.  The topology of pointwise convergence on $\mathcal F$ is the topology of $\mathbb R$, identifying $a$ with the function $f_a$.  Obviously $\arg \max_{x\in K} f_a$ is $-1$ if $a<0$ and $1$ if $a>0$ and I-don't-know-what if $a=0$.  It doesn't look like a continuous function of $a$ to me.