# Existence of Borel measurable argmax-function given semicontinuity

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

Let $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be standard Borel (that is, a Polish space endowed with the sigma algebra generated by the open sets its metric topology), and $\mathcal{A}$ be compact.

Suppose $f : \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinuous.

Then the set $A_s = \mathrm{argmax}_{a \in \mathcal{A}} f(s, a) \neq \emptyset$ is non-empty for any $s \in \mathcal{S}$.

**Q**: Does there exist a measurable function $\phi : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{A}$ such that
$\phi(s) \in A_s$ for all $s \in \mathcal{S}$ ?

By axiom of choice one may pick at least one function $\psi : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{A}$ with $\psi(s) \in A_s, \;\forall s \in \mathcal{S}$.
However I am lost as to how to know if any such function can be chosen to be measurable.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: This falls into the problem of "measurable selectors". If you run a search on this website you will find something.

Comment: For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429961/8157) is related.

Comment: Nitpick: since you're using the topology and not just the $\sigma$-algebra, you probably want to say "Polish" instead of "standard Borel".

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks. I made a small edit, hope it clarifies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes and is the question is basically proposition 7.33 in
[this book](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/soc.html).

Thanks to @Giuseppe Negro, for pointing me to the source.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped.